# AJAX - How to run a script inside a popup menu

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a popup menu that opens and displays text at the moment. What I want is to be able to attach a controller to the popup menu. For example: I want an edit profile popup to display with all the necessary inputs to edit the profile.

userprofile_view.php:

```
        <div class="upload">
    <?php
        $data = array('id' => 'test'); 
        echo form_open('', $data); 
        echo form_submit('upload', 'Upload'); 
        echo form_close(); 
    ?>
    </div>      
<div id="popupbox">     
            <center>
                <p class="head">Terms and Conditions</p>

                <p class="term_full">By entering your email, you allow Musiclear to send you information regarding Musiclear and 
                    related services <br><br> By entering your email, you also understand that you can break our hearts and unsubscribe 
                    at anypoint.  <br><br> And feel free kick us if we ever share your email address (you can trust us)</p>
            </center>

        </div>
```

This is the html behind the button and the popup form.

main.js:

```
$( "#test" ).submit(function( event ) {
   event.preventDefault();
   document.getElementById('popupbox').style.visibility="visible";
});
```

On the button click I make the form visible.

How can I make this work with a form in the popup menu?

**EDIT:**

upload controller(what I want to show in the popup):

```
function do_upload_profilepicture()
{

$this->load->model('model_users');
$userID = $this->model_users->getUserID($this->session->userdata('username'));

$config['upload_path'] = './img/profilepictures/';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png';
$config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
$config['file_name'] = $userID;
$config['max_size'] = '500';
$config['max_width']  = '1920';
$config['max_height']  = '1028';

$this->load->library('upload', $config);


if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
{
    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

    $this->load->view('upload_profilepic_form', $error);
}
else
{
    $upload_data = $this->upload->data();

    $resize['image_library'] = 'gd2';
    $resize['source_image'] = $upload_data['full_path'];
    $resize['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;
    $resize['width']     = 180;
    $resize['height']   = 180;

    $this->load->library('image_lib', $resize); 
    $this->image_lib->resize();     
    $this->image_lib->clear();
    $this->model_users->setProfilePic($userID, $upload_data['orig_name']);


    $this->create_thumb($upload_data['orig_name']);
    redirect('userprofile/home/' . $userID);


}
}
```

userprofile_view.php(popupbox):

```
        <div id="popupbox">     
        <?php echo form_open_multipart('upload/do_upload_profilepicture');?>


        <input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" />

        <br /><br />

        <input type="submit" value="upload" />

        </form>

    </div>
```

Comment: Optimize this? There is no optimization needed for this. Are you asking how to add functionality to the pop-up?

Comment: Sorry yea wrong wording ima change that

Comment: Adding functionality to the popup is no different than adding an event handler just as you have done for `#test`.

Comment: Do you have a button or link in your popup? Or do you want the script to run automatically when the popup is activated?

Comment: Automatically when its activated

Comment: It should just popup and show the upload form

Comment: Put the form in the popup markup, nothing needs to run until you're ready to do the upload. Then add an event handler for the upload form.

Comment: Im not quite sure what you mean by putting the form in the popup markup. Do you just mean to put all of the buttons and forms inside the popup div and attach the functions to the onclicks and what not?

Comment: Yes! That is exactly what you should do.

Comment: It works but on the button click it says the page isnt found, yet it is and works when I dont do it in the popup

Comment: Without seeing a more complete code example it would be hard for us to know where the issue is. Can you edit your OP to show the popup form, the function that is supposed to work and the PHP page it calls?

Comment: Take a look at my update

Comment: I added the code as you asked

Comment: Did you try putting the function call inside of script tags?

Comment: Its working now! :D Thanks. if you want you can post an answer and il vote it up and accept it

Comment: Done @Divergent - glad to help you figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your function call inside of script tags -

```
<div id="popupbox">

    <?php 
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
        echo "form_open_multipart('upload/do_upload_profilepicture');";
        echo '</script>';
    ?>
    <input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" />
    <br /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="upload" />
    </form>
</div>
```